# How to remove pulseaudio?

Tags: pulseaudio

I tried apt remove and purge, both return

`Package 'pulseaudio' is not installed, so not removed`

`fuser -fv /dev/snd/*`

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  root        387 f.... alsactl
                     root       3169 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  root        387 f.... alsactl
                     root       3169 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D1p:   root       3169 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c:   root       3169 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/timer:      root       3169 f.... pulseaudio
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use Debian Linux or a derivative, Ubuntu for example. You can try:

`apt purge *pulseaudio*`

or

`aptitude purge ~npulseaudio`

But you may have dependency problems; be extra careful on ubuntu, probably most of your system will be wiped! In my minimal Debian setup, I had no such issue.

So after the above commands, check what can be removed and what not. Try to remove the suggested packages one by one.

Comment: Thank you. 'apt purge pulseaudio' returns 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 181 not upgraded. Before that I see a lot messages stating 'package pulseaudio-..xyz is not installed so not removed'

Comment: Try `apt purge *pulse*`. But be very careful. Answer no, you do not want to remove any packages; copy the suggested packages list to an editor. In my Debian 10 system, what needed to be left installed was `libpulse0` and `libpulse-mainloop-glib0`, so keep these two and any app you need to have installed (`vlc` for example). `libpulse0` and `libpulse-mainloop-glib0` are not loaded when booting or bloat your system, they are dependencies for other apps, like `vlc`. All apps that I use which need `libpulse0` as dependency work fine with ALSA.

Comment: Then re-run apt purge, adding all the unnecessary packages as arguments. Check the list again, ideally you should see only the ones you entered to be removed.